# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2) src/node_modules/playwright/bin/PrintDeps.exe

Tags: javascript, webpack, playwright, electron-react-boilerplate

I trying to run a playwright script on my electron-react app but I am getting this error when it gets to the playwright code.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
src/node_modules/playwright/bin/PrintDeps.exe
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this raw-loader to your webpack config

`yarn add raw-loader -D`

```
{
    test: /\.exe$/i,
    use: 'raw-loader',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add playwridght in bundledDependencies in package.json

"bundledDependencies": [
"playwright"
],

and connect it's to webpack.config.js using `webpack-node-externals`

it's permit not add playwright in bundle.js, but save it as external dependency

Comment: add it in "externals" not "bundledDependencies"